# How to Compare the values in two different tables and return if any of value from a row is different in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables [Product1] and [Product2_transform]

```
create table [product1](
     [product_id]           nvarchar(256)
    ,[product_rev]          nvarchar(256)
    ,[product_name]         nvarchar(256)
    ,[product_description]  nvarchar(256)
    ,[product_owner]        nvarchar(256)
    ,[product_group]        nvarchar(256)
    ,[product_type]         nvarchar(256)
);

create table [product2_transform](
     [product_id]           nvarchar(256)
    ,[product_rev]          nvarchar(256)
    ,[product_name]         nvarchar(256)
    ,[product_description]  nvarchar(256)
    ,[product_owner]        nvarchar(256)
    ,[product_group]        nvarchar(256)
    ,[product_type]         nvarchar(256)
);


insert into [product1] values
     ('111' ,'AAA',  'CAR'          ,   'SPARE PARTS'       ,   'Nissan'        ,   'Nissan'    ,   'AUTOMOTIVE'    )   
    ,('222' ,'BBB',  'MODEL'        ,   'DESGIN'            ,   'NIFT'          ,   'NIFT'      ,   'FASHION'       )
    ,('333' ,'CCC',  'REAR'         ,   'REAR MATERIAL'     ,   'KLM'           ,   'KLM GROUP' ,   'MANUFACTURING' )
    ,('444' ,'DDD',  'FINACLE 2.0'  ,   'BANKING PRODUCT'   ,   'IFLEX'         ,   'ORACLE'    ,   'SOFTWARE'      )
    ,('555' ,'EEE',  'TYRE'         ,   'CEAR TYRES'        ,   'TATA MOTORS'   ,   'TATA'      ,   'AUTOMOTIVE'    );

insert into [product2_transform] values
     ('111',    'AAA', 'CAR'            ,   'SPARE PARTS Ford'  ,   'Ford'          , 'Nissan  '    , 'AUTOMOTIVE LTD')
    ,('222',    'BBB', 'MODEL'          ,   'DESGIN'            ,   'NIFTY'         , 'NIFT'        , 'FASHION'       )
    ,('333',    'CCC', 'REAR Head Left' ,   'REAR MATERIAL'     ,   'KLM'           , 'KLM GROUP'   , 'MANUFACTURING' )
    ,('444',    'DDD', 'FINACLE 2.5'    ,   'BANKING PRODUCT'   ,   'Oracle IFLEX'  , 'ORACLE'      , 'SOFTWARE'      )
    ,('555',    'EEE', 'SEAT TYRE'      ,   'CEAR TYRES'        ,   'TATA BANCS'    , 'TATA'        , 'AUTOMOTIVE'    );
```

I want the difference values in [product1] and [product2] and place it in [Product_post_validation] table..

```
create table [product_post_validation](
     [product_id]           nvarchar(256)
    ,[product_rev]          nvarchar(256)
    ,[validation_column]    nvarchar(256)
    ,[value_in_transform]   nvarchar(256)    
    ,[value_in_output]      nvarchar(256)
);
```

Expected result in [product_post_validation] is:
Product_id / Product_rev / validation_column / value_in_transform / value_in_output

```
111 AAA Product_description SPARE PARTS SPARE PARTS Ford
111 AAA Product_owner   Nissan  Ford
111 AAA Product_TYPE    AUTOMOTIVE  AUTOMOTIVE LTD
333 CCC Product_Name    REAR    REAR Head Left
444 DDD Product_Name    FINACLE 2.0 FINACLE 2.5
444 DDD Product_owner   IFLEX   Oracle IFLEX 
555 EEE Product_Name    TYRE    SEAT TYRE
555 EEE Product_owner   TATA MOTORS TATA BANCS
```

please help in writing query...

Actually i wrote in oracle query its working fine, now i want to write in MS sql server,so please assist.

```
with comp as (  
  select /*+ qb_name(CDC_GROUP) */  
      "PRODUCT_ID", "PRODUCT_REV", "PRODUCT_NAME", "PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION",  
      "PRODUCT_OWNER", "PRODUCT_GROUP", "PRODUCT_TYPE",  
    case when count(*) over(partition by "PRODUCT_ID", "PRODUCT_REV") - Z##NEW_CNT <= 1  
      then 'PRODUCT2_TRANSFORM'  
      else 'PRODUCT1'  
    end TBL  
  FROM (  
    select /*+ qb_name(COMPARE) NO_MERGE */  
      "PRODUCT_ID", "PRODUCT_REV", "PRODUCT_NAME", "PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION",  
      "PRODUCT_OWNER", "PRODUCT_GROUP", "PRODUCT_TYPE",  
      sum(Z##NEW_CNT) Z##NEW_CNT  
    FROM (  
      select /*+ qb_name(old) */  
      "PRODUCT_ID", "PRODUCT_REV", "PRODUCT_NAME", "PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION",  
      "PRODUCT_OWNER", "PRODUCT_GROUP", "PRODUCT_TYPE",  
      -1 Z##NEW_CNT  
      from PRODUCT1 O  
      union all  
      select /*+ qb_name(new) */  
      "PRODUCT_ID", "PRODUCT_REV", "PRODUCT_NAME", "PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION",  
      "PRODUCT_OWNER", "PRODUCT_GROUP", "PRODUCT_TYPE",  
      1 Z##NEW_CNT  
      from product2_transform N  
    )  
    group by  
      "PRODUCT_ID", "PRODUCT_REV", "PRODUCT_NAME", "PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION",  
      "PRODUCT_OWNER", "PRODUCT_GROUP", "PRODUCT_TYPE"  
    having sum(Z##NEW_CNT) != 0  
  )  
)  
select * from comp  
unpivot(val for col in(PRODUCT_NAME, PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION, PRODUCT_OWNER, PRODUCT_GROUP, PRODUCT_TYPE))  
pivot(max(val) for tbl in ('PRODUCT1' PRODUCT1, 'PRODUCT2_TRANSFORM' PRODUCT2_TRANSFORM))  
where decode(PRODUCT1, PRODUCT2_TRANSFORM, 0, 1) = 1  
order by 1,2,3;
```

Comment: Actually my query is working in oracle but not working in MS sql server. please help in this. Am learning sqlserver now. so please help in query rewriting.

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your current SQL Server query attempt, and the Oracle query.

Comment: `111 AAA Product_TYPE    AUTOMOTIVE  AUTOMOTIVE LTD`? This data doesn't even appear in your source data. How are we meant to figure this out? Magic?

Comment: What is the standard you are currently using to mark a row as unique? Do you consider all the columns? Because I can see that even the ids are same, in `product1` and `product2` tables.

Comment: here i want to find out the difference in values of each column in product1 and product_transform tables..
ex:-
product1:-
Product_id  Product_rev Product_Name    Product_description Product_owner   Product_Group   Product_TYPE
111 AAA CAR SPARE PARTS Nissan  Nissan  AUTOMOTIVE

Product2_transform:-111 AAA CAR SPARE PARTS Ford    Ford    Nissan  AUTOMOTIVE LTD

output:-Product_post_validation 
111 AAA Product_description SPARE PARTS SPARE PARTS Ford

Comment: Are you sure that this expected outcome is right (according to sample tables)?

Comment: Could you please tidy up the input?

Answer (score 1):

I would do this by unpivoting the data and then comparing:

```
with p1 as (
      select p.product_id, p.product_rev, v.col, v.val
      from product1 p cross apply
           (values ('product_name', product_name),
                   ('product_description', product_description),
                   ('product_owner', product_owner),
                   ('product_group', product_group),
                   ('product_type', product_type)
           ) v(col, val)
     ),
     p2 as (
      select p.product_id, p.product_rev, v.col, v.val
      from Product2_Transform p cross apply
           (values ('product_name', product_name),
                   ('product_description', product_description),
                   ('product_owner', product_owner),
                   ('product_group', product_group),
                   ('product_type', product_type)
           ) v(col, val)
     )
select p1.product_id, p2.product_id, p1.which as validation_column,
       p2.val as val_in_transform, p1.val as val_in_product
from p1 join
     p2
     on p1.product_id = p2.product_id and
        p1.product_rev = p2.product_rev and
        p1.col = p2.col and
        (p1.val <> p2.val or p1.val is null and p2.val is not null or p1.val is not null and p2.val is null);
```

The big issue with the unpivot is that the types need to be compatible.  They all appear to be strings, so this should be fine.

Note that this does handle `NULL` values.  It does not handle missing product/rev pairs between the two tables.  That is easily handled by using `full join` and then `coalesce()` in the `select`.  Your question is not clear if this is a priority.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: thank you for interesting challenge :)

Potential solution is:

```
;with [data] as (
    select
         [product_id]           =   isnull([p1].[product_id],   [p2].[product_id])
        ,[product_rev]          =   isnull([p1].[product_rev],  [p2].[product_rev])
        ,[validation_column1]   =   [p1_c].[value]('(local-name(.))[1]',    'nvarchar(256)')
        ,[validation_column2]   =   [p2_c].[value]('(local-name(.))[1]',    'nvarchar(256)')
        ,[validation_value1]    =   iif([p1_c].[value]('(@xsi:nil)[1]', 'bit') = 'true', null, [p1_c].[value]('(.)[1]', 'nvarchar(256)'))
        ,[validation_value2]    =   iif([p2_c].[value]('(@xsi:nil)[1]', 'bit') = 'true', null, [p2_c].[value]('(.)[1]', 'nvarchar(256)'))
    from     
        [product1]              as  [p1]
    full join
        [product2_transform]    as  [p2]
    on
            [p1].[product_id]   =   [p2].[product_id]
        and [p1].[product_rev]  =   [p2].[product_rev]
    cross apply
        (
            select [data] = convert(xml, (select [p1].* for xml path(''), elements xsinil))                      
        )                       as  [p1x]
    cross apply
        (
            select [data] = convert(xml, (select [p2].* for xml path(''), elements xsinil))                      
        )                       as  [p2x]
    cross apply 
        [p1x].[data].[nodes]('*')   as  [p1_t]([p1_c])
    cross apply 
        [p2x].[data].[nodes]('*')   as  [p2_t]([p2_c])
)
insert into [product_post_validation](
     [product_id]           
    ,[product_rev]          
    ,[validation_column]    
    ,[value_in_transform]       
    ,[value_in_output]  
)
select
     [product_id]           =   [product_id]            
    ,[product_rev]          =   [product_rev]           
    ,[validation_column]    =   isnull([validation_column1], [validation_column2])     
    ,[value_in_transform]   =   [validation_value1]   
    ,[value_in_output]      =   [validation_value2]     
from 
    [data]
where       
        isnull(nullif([validation_column1], [validation_column2]),  nullif([validation_column2],    [validation_column1]))  is null
    and isnull(nullif([validation_value1],  [validation_value2]),   nullif([validation_value2],     [validation_value1]))   is not null
order by 
     [product_id]   asc
    ,[product_rev]  asc;
```

Full testing script: https://pastebin.com/0eBuiHMX

Comment: @gpr - little fix added to support NULL cases. Now it shows NULL as diff too, and, there are no hardcoded columns. And, data type doesnt matters - script handles all common data types without changing script code.